# Hot-deploy Liferay 7 webapp resource (JavaScript/CSS/HTML)

Tags: liferay-7

I am developing a Liferay 7 portlet with bundled Tomcat 7.

To deploying a portlet, I copy the war file into deploy folder under Liferay home folder, and then I have to wait a lot of minutes to see my file modified.

Usually I work only on javascript, css and html, I want to see immediately what I changed, then, is there a way to have hot deploy for webapp resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Liferay workspaces and modules. If it is a theme, the gulp watch task will help.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay cache all resources by default, because that you have to wait a lot of time to see the changes. You have 3 ways to force Liferay to delete this cache.

1. Before deploy the module you must delete the module cache folder. This is in the following path (**this applies to js and jsp resources**):

> liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/work/your_module_name

2. Delete the module cache servlet folder located in:

> liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/css/http_/o
>   /your_module_name

3. The other option is enter in Liferay Control Panel and click the cache action tasks:

[image]